# How to return Company Name by Product Id?

Tags: product-attribute

I'm very new on this..

[image]

I have this table on my Admin Panel, on tab **Catalog** > **Manage Products**, i want to display Attribute "**Seller Company Name**" how can i display that Attribute on my .phtml file??

i usually used `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` to display each product

thanks

**UPDATE**

seller_id with 'Seller' label:

[image]

this is my getLoadedProductCollection()

```
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    return $this->_getProductCollection();
}


protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

Comment: you should post your complete phtml file code and also mention your attribute type.

Comment: exactly like mr Abdul answer sir, but on my Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List class there's no getCompany() function, i'm still working on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display bellow way in your.phtml file

```
  <?php
        $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSellerId() , 'seller_id'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for reply :) i think in my model there's no getSellerCompanyName() sir.. do you know how to create function to display Seller Company Name column on my picture? i've been triying but no progress

Comment: are you need backend or frantend?

Comment: my code have same structure as yours, but when i print $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSellerCompanyName() , 'seller_company_name'); cause my model theres no function called getSellerCompanyName and this is my second problem

Comment: Can you share your attribute code?

Comment: backend sir.. on my model, i have tried print $_product->getProductUrl() and its works

Comment: Pls share all code qus

Comment: wait a sec sir, i'll find first..

Comment: or add 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id') ->addAttributeToSelect('your_attribute_code')

Comment: in function getLoadedProductCollection()

Comment: is this my attribute code??
Array ( [0] => Array ( [attribute_id] => 1 [entity_type_id] => 1 [attribute_code] => website_id [attribute_model] => [backend_model] => customer/customer_attribute_backend_website [backend_type] => static [backend_table] => [frontend_model] => [frontend_input] => select [frontend_label] => Associate to Website [frontend_class] => [source_model] => customer/customer_attribute_source_website [is_required] => 1 [is_user_defined] => 0 [default_value] => [is_unique] => 0 [note] => )

Comment: ahh this ismy attr code for company name:  
( [attribute_id] => 24 [entity_type_id] => 2 [attribute_code] => company [attribute_model] => [backend_model] => [backend_type] => varchar [backend_table] => [frontend_model] => [frontend_input] => text [frontend_label] => Company [frontend_class] => [source_model] => [is_required] => 0 [is_user_defined] => 0 [default_value] => [is_unique] => 0 [note] => )

Comment: is product attribute right?

Comment: yess, for product_id 24 sir

Comment: ok now share your function getLoadedProductCollection() code

Comment: Only add code : ->addAttributeToSelect('company') in your getLoadedProductCollection() function and after dispaly  $_product->getCompany(); in .phtml file

Comment: i added getLoadedProductCollection() function on my post sir,

i don't a see addAttributeToSelect() on getLoadedProductCollection(), but i found this:
    public function addAttribute($code)
    {
        $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect($code);
        return $this;
    }
i have no idea where this function called :(

Comment: updates ans pls check now

Comment: still null sir :( already added this $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('company') too

Comment: are you going total wrong way

Comment: you are use code fronted end

Comment: Pls "company" is customer attribute

Comment: Pls give me your "Seller Company Name" attribute code

Comment: i just touching magento last day sir :( wait a sec

Comment: attr code for company name: ( [attribute_id] => 24 [entity_type_id] => 2 [attribute_code] => company [attribute_model] => [backend_model] => [backend_type] => varchar [backend_table] => [frontend_model] => [frontend_input] => text [frontend_label] => Company [frontend_class] => [source_model] => [is_required] => 0 [is_user_defined] => 0 [default_value] => [is_unique] => 0 [note] => )

Comment: this is customer address attr code

Comment: Go admin side Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attributes and find your attr code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34180/discussion-on-answer-by-abdul-how-to-return-company-name-by-product-id).

Comment: ahh... its just seller_id on there sir, there's no company name/seller name..

Comment: updates ans pls check now

Comment: thanks sir Abdul, its works now :) seller_id has apear after i added new attributes on admin panel, but my problem is to display Seller Name..

when i edit some product on Manage Products, its shows seller name (picture on my UPDATED post) but when i called like your script its a seller_id..

Comment: and its appear when i just print this $_product->getSellerId()